# I am trying to append to a file from user input (python3.x) don't get why this code won't work

Tags: python-3.x, io, user-input

My code basically takes user input and puts it in a file. When I run it, the code creates the file, but it is always empty. Can you help me?

```
  #Asks file name from user.
  FileName = input("Please provide a name for your file: (no spaces) ")
  FileFullName = FileName + ".txt"
  TypeInput = input("What would you like to type? ")
  FileLine = TypeInput + "\n"
  #Opens file & puts user input into file.
  saveFile = open(FileFullName, 'a')
  saveFile.write(FileLine)
  print("All finished!")
  saveFile.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in this site. Always be specific and make your best effort before asking. In this case, you show us your error and there are 1000 of possibilities for that error. I recommend you to add some piece of code. Then we can try to fix it or give you an advice.

Comment: By the way, don't capitalize your variables in Python, they should be `lower_underscored`. It helps us python people read it

Comment: Are you looking in the right folder for the output file? Seems like it should work as-is.

Comment: No, I tried that too. Do you think my compiler is old?

Comment: Sorry I am stupid, I meant *python version*, not compiler

Answer (score 0):

Use `with open` so u don't need to close a file. It works like this:

```
#Asks file name from user.
FileName = input("Please provide a name for your file: (no spaces) ")
FileFullName = FileName + ".txt"
TypeInput = input("What would you like to type? ")
FileLine = TypeInput + "\n"
#Opens file & puts user input into file.
with open(FileFullName, 'a') as saveFile:
    saveFile.write(FileLine)
print("All finished!")
```